# Minecraft sprinting and Hitting Problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I am using a iMac. My sprint button is set as control (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>). When I try and sprint and hit at the same time it will not hit. It is as if I didn't click the mouse, my hand doesn't move. However, I can build. Could this be to do with shortcuts and if so, how do I fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: Does the mouse button work when holding `CTRL + W` in other games?

Answer (score 3):

You should change the sprint key to a different one (I suggest <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>), because in Macs,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Click is considered as Right click.